# Create a popup message in Powershell

Tags: function, powershell, popup, global-functions

I'm attempting to make a function that will allow me to popup a please wait message run some more script then close the popup

```
Function Popup-Message {

    param ([switch]$show,[switch]$close)

    Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms  

    # Build Form
    $objForm = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
    $objForm.Text = "Test"
    $objForm.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(220,100)

    # Add Label
    $objLabel = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
    $objLabel.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(80,20) 
    $objLabel.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(100,20)
    $objLabel.Text = "Hi there!"
    $objForm.Controls.Add($objLabel)



    If ($show)
    {
        $objForm.Show() | Out-Null
        $global:test = "Show"
    }


    If ($close)
    {
        # destroy form
        $objForm.Close() | Out-Null
        $global:test = "Close"
    }
}
```

I can then get the popup to display by:

```
Popup-Message -show
```

At this point I can see the **$test** variable as **Show**

But when I try to close the window with:

```
Popup-Message -close
```

But the popup window will not close
If I look at **$test** again it will show as **Close**

I'm assuming this has something to do with keeping the function in the Global Scope but I can't figure out how to do this with the form

Comment: Your usage of a switch parameter (which is either $true or $false) is paradox. Change to `if($show){"this"]else["that"}`

Comment: As an aside: Please avoid pseudo method syntax: instead of `New-Object SomeType(arg1, ...)`, use `New-Object SomeType [-ArgumentList] arg1, ...` - PowerShell cmdlets and functions are invoked like _shell commands_ (no parentheses, whitespace-separated arguments), not like _methods_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[kpogue's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55013720/45375) explains your problem well and offers a solution that is effective, but suboptimal due to relying on *global variables*.

Let me suggest a different approach, where you **use a function to simply *define* the form and *return that definition*, on which you can call the `.Show()` and `.Close()` *methods* as needed**, but note that the `.Show()` method is overridden via [`Add-Member`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/add-member) to include a call to `[System.Windows.Forms.Application]::DoEvents()`, so as to ensure that the form is properly drawn.

```
function New-PopUpForm {

  Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms  

  # Create the form.
  $objForm = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form -Property @{
    Text            = "Test"
    Size            = New-Object System.Drawing.Size 220, 100
    StartPosition   = 'CenterScreen' # Center on screen.
    FormBorderStyle = 'FixedSingle'  # fixed-size form
    # Remove interaction elements (close button, system menu).
    ControlBox      = $false
  }

  # Create a label...
  $objLabel = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label -Property @{
    Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size 80, 20
    Size     = New-Object System.Drawing.Size 100, 20
    Text     = "Hi there!"
  }

  # ... and add it to the form.
  $objForm.Controls.Add($objLabel)

  # Override the `.Show()` method to include
  # a [System.Windows.Forms.Application]::DoEvents(), so as 
  # to ensure that the form is properly drawn.
  $objForm | Add-Member -Force -Name Show -MemberType ScriptMethod -Value {
    $this.psbase.Show() # Call the original .Show() method.
    # Activate the form (focus it).
    $this.Activate()
    [System.Windows.Forms.Application]::DoEvents() # Ensure proper drawing.
  }

  # Since this form is meant to be called with .Show() but without 
  # a [System.Windows.Forms.Application]::DoEvents() *loop*, it
  # it is best to simply *hide* the cursor (mouse pointer), so as not
  # to falsely suggest that interaction with the form is possible
  # and so as not to end up with a stuck "wait" cursor (mouse pointer) on 
  # the first instantiation in a session.
  [System.Windows.Forms.Cursor]::Hide()

  # Return the form.
  return $objForm
}
```

You can then use the function as follows:

```
$form = New-PopupForm

$form.Show() 

# ...

$form.Close()
```

**Note**:

- Once you call `.Close()`, the form instance stored in `$form` is disposed of and cannot be reused - simply call `New-PopupForm` again to create a new instance.
- If the PowerShell session running your script *exits*, any pop-up windows created in the session close automatically.

**Caveats**:

- Note that, **due to use of the `.Show()` method (without additional effort), the user won't be able to *interact* with the pop-up window**, notably not even in order to  *move* the window or close it *manually*.

  - If, such as in your case, the window isn't meant to be interacted with, this isn't a problem, however.
  - Setting `ControlBox = $false` above removes the window's close button and system menu so as to make it obvious that no interaction is possible.
  - Hiding the cursor (mouse pointer) with `[System.Windows.Forms.Cursor]::Hide()` serves the same purpose.

    - **Note**: *Not* hiding the cursor causes the "wait" cursor to be shown (indicating that the form is busy processing something) indefinitely while mousing over the form, but curiously only for the very first instance created in a session. The only way to avoid it that I know of is to enter an event loop after calling `.Show()`, as discussed in the last bullet point.
- By contrast, **`.ShowDialog()` *would* allow interaction, but *blocks further execution* of your script** until the window is closed by the user.
- If you need to *combine* the two approaches - **allowing the user to interact with the window while continuing to do processing in your PowerShell script** - you need to **call `[System.Windows.Forms.Application]::DoEvents()` *in a loop***, as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62410153/45375).

  - If you use this approach, you should remove the `[System.Windows.Forms.Cursor]::Hide()` call from the function.

Comment: Thanks, how would I go about setting the cursor to `Arrow`?

Comment: @Ste, unfortunately there is no good answer - please see my update. In short: unless you're prepared to enter an explicit `[System.Windows.Forms.Application]::DoEvents()` after calling `.Show()`, the "wait" cursor will linger, though curiously seemingly only with the first form instance in a session.

Answer (score 1):

You're creating a new instance of the form in each call to Popup-Message.  So, the form is not closing becausing you're trying to close a new form which has never been opened. Meanwhile, the old form no longer has anyone referencing it, it's just sitting out in space. You can create a global reference as shown below, there are probably more artful ways of doing this.

```
Function Popup-Message {

param ([switch]$show,[switch]$close)

Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms  

# Build Form
if ($Global:objForm -eq $null){
$Global:objForm = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$Global:objForm.Text = "Test"
$Global:objForm.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(220,100)

# Add Label
$Global:objLabel = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$Global:objLabel.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(80,20) 
$Global:objLabel.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(100,20)
$Global:objLabel.Text = "Hi there!"
$Global:objForm.Controls.Add($objLabel)
}



If ($show)
{
    $Global:objForm.Show() | Out-Null
    $global:test = "Show"
}


If ($close)
{
    # destroy form
    $Global:objForm.Close() | Out-Null
    $global:test = "Close"
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

we can use One line to create the powershell popup with Wscript.Shell COM object

Syntax: **intButton = objShell.Popup(strText,[nSecondsToWait],[strTitle],[nType])**

```
#creating object os WScript
$wshell = New-Object -ComObject Wscript.Shell -ErrorAction Stop
#invoking the POP method using object
$wshell.Popup("please wait message?",5,"Wait Until Scrip execution",48+4)
```

Comment: Not really what I was looking for.  This is essentially a fancy Start-Sleep function.  I have no way to know how long the rest of the script is going to take as it is going to be used to convert AppV sequences that can be anywhere from 20 MB to over 1.5 GB so far.