# In Powershell how can I change Label text after a successful copy files?

Tags: powershell, winforms

I start building up a small winform with Copy button and a label under this button.
When I click on Copy button it starts to copy files from source to destination.
I would like to run this **asynchroniously** so I don't want form to be freezed while copy operation runs. That's why I use Job. After a successful copy I need feedback of copy and show an "OK" text with green color but it is not working.

Here is my code:

```
[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms")
[System.Windows.Forms.Application]::EnableVisualStyles()

Function Copy-Action{

    $Computername = "testclient"

    $Source_Path = "C:\temp\"
    $Destination_Path = "\\$Computername\c$\temp"


    $job = Start-Job -Name "Copy" -ArgumentList $Source_Path,$Destination_Path –ScriptBlock {
           param($Source_Path,$Destination_Path) 
                    
           Copy-Item $Source_Path -Destination $Destination_Path -Recurse -Force
            
            } 
 
    Register-ObjectEvent $job StateChanged -MessageData $Status_Label -Action {
        [Console]::Beep(1000,500)
        $Status_Label.Text = "OK"
        $Status_Label.ForeColor = "#009900"
        $eventSubscriber | Unregister-Event
        $eventSubscriber.Action | Remove-Job
        } | Out-Null
}

# DRAW FORM
$form_MainForm = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$form_MainForm.Text = "Test Copy"
$form_MainForm.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(200,200)
$form_MainForm.FormBorderStyle = "FixedDialog"
$form_MainForm.StartPosition = "CenterScreen"
$form_MainForm.MaximizeBox = $false
$form_MainForm.MinimizeBox = $true
$form_MainForm.ControlBox = $true

# Copy Button
$Copy_Button = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$Copy_Button.Location = "50,50"
$Copy_Button.Size = "75,30"
$Copy_Button.Text = "Copy"
$Copy_Button.Add_Click({Copy-Action})
$form_MainForm.Controls.Add($Copy_Button)

# Status Label
$Status_Label = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$Status_Label.Text = ""
$Status_Label.AutoSize = $true
$Status_Label.Location = "75,110"
$Status_Label.ForeColor = "black"
$form_MainForm.Controls.Add($Status_Label)

#show form
$form_MainForm.Add_Shown({$form_MainForm.Activate()})
[void] $form_MainForm.ShowDialog()
```

Copy is successful but showing an "OK" label won't. I have placed a Beep but it doesn't work too.
What am I doing wrong ? Any solution to this?
Thank you.

Comment: Displaying the form blocks code execution until it is closed.

Comment: Then there is no solution? Or it is complicated? :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Start-Job` creates a separate process, and when your form is ready to receive events, it can't listen to job events. You need to create a new runspace, which is able to synchronize thread and form control.

I adapted code from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40808521/17350874). You can read much better explanation there.

```
[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms")
[System.Windows.Forms.Application]::EnableVisualStyles()

Function Copy-Action{

    $SyncHash = [hashtable]::Synchronized(@{TextBox = $Status_Label})
    $Runspace = [runspacefactory]::CreateRunspace()
    $Runspace.ThreadOptions = "UseNewThread"
    $Runspace.Open()
    $Runspace.SessionStateProxy.SetVariable("SyncHash", $SyncHash)          
    $Worker = [PowerShell]::Create().AddScript({
        $SyncHash.TextBox.Text = "Copying..."
        
        # Copy-Item
        $Computername = "testclient"

        $Source_Path = "C:\temp\"
        $Destination_Path = "\\$Computername\c$\temp"

        Copy-Item $Source_Path -Destination $Destination_Path -Recurse -Force

        
        $SyncHash.TextBox.ForeColor = "#009900"
        $SyncHash.TextBox.Text = "OK"

    })
    $Worker.Runspace = $Runspace
    $Worker.BeginInvoke()

}

# DRAW FORM
$form_MainForm = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$form_MainForm.Text = "Test Copy"
$form_MainForm.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(200,200)
$form_MainForm.FormBorderStyle = "FixedDialog"
$form_MainForm.StartPosition = "CenterScreen"
$form_MainForm.MaximizeBox = $false
$form_MainForm.MinimizeBox = $true
$form_MainForm.ControlBox = $true

# Copy Button
$Copy_Button = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$Copy_Button.Location = "50,50"
$Copy_Button.Size = "75,30"
$Copy_Button.Text = "Copy"
$Copy_Button.Add_Click({Copy-Action})
$form_MainForm.Controls.Add($Copy_Button)

# Status Label
$Status_Label = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$Status_Label.Text = ""
$Status_Label.AutoSize = $true
$Status_Label.Location = "75,110"
$Status_Label.ForeColor = "black"
$form_MainForm.Controls.Add($Status_Label)

#show form
$form_MainForm.Add_Shown({$form_MainForm.Activate()})
[void] $form_MainForm.ShowDialog()
```

Comment: How it is possible to pass a variable ($ComputerName) to the worker block?

Comment: Just add a line `$Runspace.SessionStateProxy.SetVariable("ComputerName", $Computername)`.

Answer (score 5):

Let me offer alternatives to [balrundel's helpful solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69915186/45375) - which is effective, but complex.

The core problem is that **while a form is being shown *modally*, with [`.ShowDialog()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Windows.Forms.Form.ShowDialog), WinForms is in control of the foreground thread, not PowerShell**.

That is, PowerShell code - in the form's event handlers - only executes in response to *user actions*, which is why your job-state-change event handler passed to [`Register-ObjectEvent`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/register-objectevent)'s `-Action` parameter does *not* fire (it would *eventually* fire, *after closing the form*).

There are **two fundamental solutions**:

- **Stick with `.ShowDialog()`** and **perform operations** in parallel, ***in a different PowerShell runspace (thread)***.

  - balrundel's solution uses the [PowerShell SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/developer/windows-powershell) to achieve this, whose use is far from trivial, unfortunately.
  - See below for a simpler alternative based on `Start-ThreadJob`
- **Show the form *non-modally*, via the [`.Show()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Windows.Forms.Form.Show) method, and enter a *loop*** in which you can perform other operations while ***periodically* calling [`[System.Windows.Forms.Application]::DoEvents()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Windows.Forms.Application.DoEvents)** in order to keep the form responsive.

  - See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62410153/45375) for an example of this technique.
  - A *hybrid* approach is to stick with `.ShowDialog()` and enter a `[System.Windows.Forms.Application]::DoEvents()` loop *inside the form event handler*.

    - This is best limited to a *single* event handler applying this technique, as using *additional* simultaneous `[System.Windows.Forms.Application]::DoEvents()` loops invites trouble.
    - See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62374199/45375) for an example of this technique.

---

Simpler, **[`Start-ThreadJob`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/threadjob/start-threadjob)-based solution**:

- `Start-ThreadJob` is part of the the [`ThreadJob` module](https://github.com/PaulHigin/PSThreadJob) that offers a **lightweight, *thread*-based alternative to the child-process-based regular background jobs** and is also a **more convenient alternative to creating runspaces via the PowerShell SDK**.

  - It **comes with *PowerShell (Core) 7+*** and **can be installed on demand in *Windows PowerShell*** with, e.g., `Install-Module ThreadJob -Scope CurrentUser`.
  - In most cases, thread jobs are the better choice, both for performance and type fidelity - see the bottom section of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59440248/45375) for why.
- In addition to syntactic convenience, `Start-ThreadJob`, due to being *thread*-based (rather than using a *child process*, which is what `Start-Job` does), allows manipulating the calling thread's live objects.

  - Note that the sample code below, in the interest of brevity, performs *no* explicit thread synchronization, which may situationally be required.

The following **simplified, self-contained sample code demonstrates** the technique:

- The sample shows a simple form with a button that starts a thread job, and updates the form from inside that thread job after the operation (simulated by a 3-second sleep) completes, as shown in the following screen shots:

  - Initial state:

    - [image: start state]
  - After pressing `Start Job` (the form remains responsive):

    - [image: running state]
  - After the job has ended:

    - [image: end state]
- The `.add_Click()` event handler contains the meat of the solution; the source-code comments hopefully provide enough documentation.

```sh
# PSv5+
using namespace System.Windows.Forms
using namespace System.Drawing

Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms

# Create a sample form.
$form = [Form] @{ 
  Text = 'Form with Thread Job'
  ClientSize = [Point]::new(200, 80)
  FormBorderStyle = 'FixedToolWindow'
}

# Create the controls and add them to the form.
$form.Controls.AddRange(@(

    ($btnStartJob = [Button] @{
        Text     = "Start Job"
        Location = [Point]::new(10, 10)
      })

    [Label] @{
      Text     = "Status:"
      AutoSize = $true
      Location = [Point]::new(10, 40)
      Font     = [Font]::new('Microsoft Sans Serif', 10)
    }

    ($lblStatus = [Label] @{
        Text     = "(Not started)"
        AutoSize = $true
        Location = [Point]::new(80, 40)
        Font     = [Font]::new('Microsoft Sans Serif', 10)
      })

  ))

# The script-level helper variable that maintains a collection of
# thread-job objects created in event-handler script blocks,
# which must be cleaned up after the form closes.
$script:jobs = @()

# Add an event handler to the button that starts 
# the background job.
$btnStartJob.add_Click( {
    $this.Enabled = $false # To prevent re-entry while the job is still running.
    # Signal the status.
    $lblStatus.Text = 'Running...'
    $form.Refresh() # Update the UI.
    # Start the thread job, and add the job-info object to 
    # the *script-level* $jobs collection.
    # The sample job simply sleeps for 3 seconds to simulate a long-running operation.
    # Note:
    #  * The $using: scope is required to access objects in the caller's thread.
    #  * In this simple case you don't need to maintain a *collection* of jobs -
    #    you could simply discard the previous job, if any, and start a new one,
    #    so that only one job object is ever maintained.
    $script:jobs += Start-ThreadJob { 
      # Perform the long-running operation.
      Start-Sleep -Seconds 3 
      # Update the status label and re-enable the button.
      ($using:lblStatus).Text = 'Done'
      ($using:btnStartJob).Enabled = $true 
    }
  })

$form.ShowDialog()

# Clean up the collection of jobs.
$script:jobs | Remove-Job -Force
```

Comment: Very nice summary, I will try this solution too. Thanks for your efforts to use your time writing all of this in order to help others with your competence. Nice, appreciate it. ☺️