# PowerShell UI hangs when using CreatePowerBiReport

Tags: powershell, user-interface, powerbi

When I call the function CreatePowerBiReport everything is working fine. But when I use the same function in a windows form then UI freezes. I use Underlying code:
Tried multiple alternatives but this it not working. The report is uploaded to the selected workspace but the UI freezes.

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
Set-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Scope CurrentUser -Force
Login-PowerBIServiceAccount

# Function to create a Power BI report
Function CreatePowerBIReport {
    Param (
        [string]$pbFilePath,
        [string]$workspaceId
    )
    New-PowerBIReport -Path $pbFilePath -WorkspaceId $workspaceId -ConflictAction CreateOrOverwrite
}

# Create a form
$form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$form.Text = 'Publish Power BI File'
$form.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(450, 200)
$form.StartPosition = 'CenterScreen'

# Create a label for selecting Power BI file
$pbFileLabel = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$pbFileLabel.Text = 'Power BI File:'
$pbFileLabel.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(20, 20)
$pbFileLabel.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(100, 20)
$form.Controls.Add($pbFileLabel)

# Create a textbox for selecting Power BI file
$pbFileTextBox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$pbFileTextBox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(130, 20)
$pbFileTextBox.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(200, 20)
$form.Controls.Add($pbFileTextBox)

# Create a button to select Power BI file
$pbFileSelectButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$pbFileSelectButton.Text = 'Browse...'
$pbFileSelectButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(340, 20)
$pbFileSelectButton.Add_Click({
    # Create an OpenFileDialog object
    $openFileDialog = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog
    $openFileDialog.Filter = "Power BI Files (*.pbix)|*.pbix"

    # Show the dialog and set the selected file path to the textbox
    if ($openFileDialog.ShowDialog() -eq 'OK') {
        $pbFileTextBox.Text = $openFileDialog.FileName
    }
})
$form.Controls.Add($pbFileSelectButton)

# Create a label for Workspace ID
$workspaceIdLabel = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$workspaceIdLabel.Text = 'Workspace ID:'
$workspaceIdLabel.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(20, 50)
$workspaceIdLabel.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(100, 20)
$form.Controls.Add($workspaceIdLabel)

# Create a textbox for Workspace ID
$workspaceIdTextBox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$workspaceIdTextBox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(130, 50)
$workspaceIdTextBox.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(200, 20)
$form.Controls.Add($workspaceIdTextBox)

# Create an "OK" button
$okButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$okButton.Text = 'OK'
$okButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(170, 100)
$okButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75, 23)
$form.Controls.Add($okButton)

# Define the action to take when the "OK" button is clicked
$okButton.Add_Click({
    # Get the selected Power BI file and Workspace ID
    $pbFilePath = $pbFileTextBox.Text
    $workspaceId = $workspaceIdTextBox.Text

    # Check if both the file path and Workspace ID are provided
    if (-not [string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($pbFilePath) -and -not [string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($workspaceId)) {
        # Run the report creation in a separate thread
        CreatePowerBIReport -pbFilePath "$($pbFileTextBox.Text)" -workspaceId $workspaceIdTextBox.Text

        [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("Power BI report creation started. You will be notified upon completion.", "Information", [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxButtons]::OK, [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxIcon]::Information)
    } else {
        [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("Please select a Power BI file and enter a Workspace ID", "Error", [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxButtons]::OK, [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxIcon]::Error)
    }
})

# Show the form
$form.ShowDialog()
```

This is the only thing I tried for now.

Comment: Your WinForm will be frozen for as long `CreatePowerBIReport` runs. To start a long-running operation from an event handler, you'll need a different approach - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69934214/45375) for options.